# Android bound service not destroyed after all clients unbind

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have 2 services A and B.

A creates B and binds to B via the Context#bindService() with the [CONTEXT_AUTO_CREATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#BIND_AUTO_CREATE) flag. Normally when A unbinds from B, B is destroyed. Under this approach, A and B are running in the same process with A's package name.

I need B running in a separate process, so I added a [android:process](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#proc) flag to B's AndroidManifest.xml. This way, when A binds & auto-creates B, B will run a separate process from A.

However, I noticed that when A unbinds from B, B continues to be up. This is against the [Android Developer guide on bound processes](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Lifecycle) - that a service is not considered "started" if [Service#onStartCommand()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) is not called. As a matter of fact, onStartCommand() is never called. But when all clients unbind from B, B continues to run. Why is that? Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How do you know that B is still running?

Comment: because i ran `adb shell ps` and still see B. Normally B would not be listed